# URL format asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I'm trying to create a URL format like

```
www.sitename.co.uk/property/dundee/dd1
```

It currently looks like

```
www.sitename.co.uk/property.aspx?Location=dundee&PostCode=dd1
```

Is their an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using IIS7 Url Rewrite this is possible.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/

```
<rule name="Property">
          <match url="^Property/(.+)/(.+)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="property.aspx?Location={R:1}&amp;PostCode={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

I've assumed that the second `?` in your URL should be an `&`?

Answer (score 1):

You can it using asp.net mvc3. The route engine inside asp.net mvc3 is so powerfull, for more info please check this site [ASP.NET MVC3 Routing](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)